# Print list items in one line along with other things

Tags: python

I have a list and I'd like to print every item in that list along with other information in one line. Any advise will be appreciated.

```
l = ['absolute', 'nicest']
print 'P', l, 'Score'
```

The output will be:

```
P ['absolute', 'nicest'] Score
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
P absolute nicest Score
```

I know that I can use a for loop to print every item in the list but the problem is I'm writing it in a function, and I don't know where to add the for loop correctly, below is the original function, I'd like to only print every item in the tl list instead of the list entirely.

```
def sa_baseline(entry):
    pl = [] #Polarity sum list
    tl = [] #Term list
    for token in entry.split():
        if token in d:
            pl.append(d[token])
            tl.append(token)
            if sum(pl) == 0:
                print 'Neu'
            elif sum(pl) > 0:
                print 'P', tl, sum(pl)
            else:
                print 'N', tl, sum(pl)
```

Comment: Try `" ".join(l)` to convert the list to a string.

Comment: @EliKorvigo What do you mean by duplicate? What could be duplicated?

Comment: @HughBothwell Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
l = ['absolute', 'nicest']
print 'P', " ".join(l), 'Score'
```

convert the list into a space separated string